# paperclip rails unable to render default url for image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have the following view to show the thumb image only the first image

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <a href="#"><%= image_tag post.uploads.first.upload.url(:thumb) %></a>
<% end %>
```

And in my model uploads.rb I set the default url like this

```
has_attached_file :upload,styles: { medium: ["500x400>",:jpg], thumb: ["150x100#",:jpg]}, default_url: '/assets/avatar.jpg', url: "/path/to/upload"
```

But I am getting error as

```
undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is because I did not upload image for this posts but why it is not rendering the default image

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have not linked any upload object to some post object in @posts. In other words, there's some post, which is not linked to any upload object, which contains normally Paperclip's methods.

If you want to show the default image for some minimum amount of unuploaded images, you can after creation of post object create that amount of 'uploads', and voila: since upload objects are in the database, but there's no image data in it, they will render a default.

And one more: it is so ambigous to name attachment same name as Model. It would be better to name attachment as "image" or "file" so url invoke would be as:

```
post.uploads.first.image.url(:thumb)
```

Comment: @user2749548 Have you renamed has_attached_file :upload ==> has_attached_file :image ?